# If a fair coin is tossed repeatedly, what is the probability that the $3rd$ head occurs on the $nth$ toss?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have solved for the case in which I found the probability that $1st$ head occurs in $nth$ toss, but I don't know how to solve for this problem which is a little bit different. Can anyone guide or help??

$PROBLEM:$

If a fair coin is tossed repeatedly, what is the probability that the $3rd$
head occurs on the $nth$ toss?

Comment: Hint;  you need exactly $2$ Heads in the first $n-1$ tosses, and you need the $n^{th}$ toss to be Heads.

Answer (score 0):

This is equal to the probability of getting 2 heads in the first $n-1$ tosses, and the 3rd head in the $n$th toss. The probability is equal to $$\binom{n-1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-3}\cdot \frac{1}{2}=\binom{n-1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n$$

Comment: Can you explain the term that expresses the probability of getting 2 heads in first n-1 tosses? How did you get it?

Comment: @AmeerShah binomial distribution, $n-1$ trials, $2$ successes, success probability $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: This question is from chapter 1 of my book. The binomial distribution has not been discussed yet. Can you explain it without binomial distribution? It will be quite helpful

Comment: https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/binomial-distribution.html this might help you, there's an example about coin flipping